# python: numpy runs script twice

Tags: python, linux, numpy

when I import numpy to my python script, the script is executed twice. 
Can someone tell me how I can stop this, since everything in my script takes twice as long?

Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from numpy import *

print 'test_start'

lines = open('test.file', 'r').readlines()
what=int(lines[0])+2
nsteps = len(lines)/what
atom_list=[]
for i in range(0,nsteps*what):
  atom_list.append(lines[i].split())

del atom_list[:]
print 'test_end'
```

And the output is:

```
test_start
test_end
test_start
test_end
```

So, is my script first executed with normal python and then with numpy again?
Maybe I should say that I have not worked with numpy yet and just wanted to start and test it.

Cheers

Comment: Is your working directory named "numpy"? rename it. and also, always use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` idiom.

Comment: @shx2: not the directory, but the exe file :) renamed it, thx

Comment: You might also want to avoid using `from numpy import *` since this overwrites common Python builtins like `sum` and `any` and `all` with the NumPy functions of the same names, leading to (potentially) surprising behavior.

Comment: @shx2: would it be better to use 'import numpy' then? you can of course post this as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script, being named `numpy.py`, unintentionaly imports itself. Since module-level code gets executed when imported, the import line causes it to run, then once the imoprt is completed, it runs the rest again.

([An explanation](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#executing-the-main-module-twice) about why a script can import itself)

Suggestions:

1. rename your script to something other than `numpy.py`
2. use the [`if __name__=='__main__'` idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) (you should always use it in your scripts)

Other than that, as already pointed out, `from numpy import *` is strongly discouraged. Either use `import numpy` or the common `import numpy as np`.