# Why does passing an int of 3 give me two rows with numpy.zeros(3)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The int passed makes a 3 element array.

`np.zeros(3)`

But it makes a 3 column array with 2 rows.

```
[0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0.]
```

What's the reason behind this? And when I pass a shape of (3,3) to np.zero()'s shape it makes even less sense. 2 of them? Looking into a duplication issue here.

```
[[0. 0. 0.]               
 [0. 0. 0.]               
 [0. 0. 0.]]              
[[0. 0. 0.]               
 [0. 0. 0.]               
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: What you're describing doesn't match the documentation. Exactly what version of numpy are you running?

Comment: You must be calling that function twice, and yes, the shape returned looks correct if you ignore the duplicates, maybe check the documentation to verify?

Comment: @user17242583 [removed] thank you. Meme Composer, Dai still working on determining what is causative to my output based on both suggestions. Thank you both as well.

Comment: Will you please send a _screenshot_ of the output? (Funny because we usually tell users _not_ to do that :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normal output:

```
In [430]: np.zeros(3)
Out[430]: array([0., 0., 0.])
In [431]: np.zeros((3,3))
Out[431]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Results after moving to Jupyter or interpreted (from vim) are absolutely as they should be. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file was originally array.py. Changing this name fixed the issue. This post helped. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28627875/17597459)

Comment: Please consider closing the question